# complexity of brute force array traversal

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, traversal

If I have a 4x4 grid for example and I want to start at an arbitrary cell (i,j) and then want to travel down every path without crossing over on myself, what is the complexity (big o) of this? I have written the following code:

```
traverse(int[][]grid, int i, int j, boolean[][] visited){
    for(int x = -1; x<=1; x++){
       for(int y=-1; y<=1; y++){
           if(inBounds(grid, i+x, j+y), !visited[i+x][j+y]){
              traverse(grid, i+x, j+y, copyOfAndSet(visited, i+x, j+y));
           }
       }
    }
}
```

assume inBounds exists and copyOfAndSet exists and is O(1) (not O(n*n)) as I have implemented this with bitwise operations but for clarity have used an array of booleans here.

What is the running time of the algorithm above on a NxN grid.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does `inBounds` do? Is it just checking whether `x` and `y` are in the bounds of `grid`? And does `copyOfAndSet` really copy the array?

Comment: inBounds does just what you said, in my real implementation I dont use a visited array instead I use an integer and set bits in O(1) time to track what nodes have been visited, hence I said for the purpose of this assume copyOfAndSet is an O(1) operation as to not complicate the algorithm. Does that make sense?

Comment: I still don’t get what you’re trying to do. What do you mean by “travel down every path without crossing over on myself”? Travel down from where to where?

Comment: Starting at a cell, let's say (0,0) I want to go to every child and from there visit every cell in the grid at most once, where each path is evaluated in isolation.

Comment: Gumbo, Please see my comment to @Szabolcs, I think that correctly summaries what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I understand your question, you want to enumerate all **self avoiding walks** on a 2D grid. (You said "travel down *every* path without crossing over on myself")

You can find several papers about this by googling for these keywords.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.8.5913

The problem seems to be #P-complete, according to the paper.

Comment: Might have misunderstood the question, let me know if this is useful.

Comment: Using this terminology, it would appear that given a starting cell(i,j) I am trying to traverse all self avoiding walks from it, to quote wikipedia: "Finding the number of such paths is conjectured to be an NP-hard problem."

Comment: That does not mean you cannot calculate the complexity of this specific algorithm. The number of paths is an exact number, O analysis is a completely different thing.

Comment: @yi_H yes, but for an NxN grid this would be NP Hard

Comment: calculating the exact number of possible paths would be NP hard. You might still be able to calculate the complexity of this program.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your algorithm can traverse diagonally, I'm not sure that's what you wanted... second: it should first visit the starting node (do a copyOfAndSet), but your algorithm first moves to the direction (-1, -1).

When traversing the array the algorithm visits every node and in every node it checks the 9 neighbours (it should check 8 BTW, (0, 0) doesn't make sense). For the `NxN` grid this is 9*N*N or simply `O(N^2)` If copyOfAndSet does actually copy the array then it's N*N work for each cell so it's `O(N^4)`.

Comment: Hi, the (i+0,j+0) coords wont be checked as the would have been set in the visited array ( I should have stated this), so this makes at most 8 neighbours visited. Secondly, I do want it to traverse diagonally as *one* possible  path, I want it to traverse every possible path that it can from the starting position without creating a loop

Comment: Also, As stated above in the question please *assume copyOfAndSet is an O(1) operation* as I am not actually using a boolean array but instead passing an int around and setting bits (which is O(1))

Comment: Well, your code just traverses one path. I can only calculate the complexity for the code you provided.

Comment: The code doesn't *just* traverse the diagonal path, once it has finished traversing the diagonal path it will backtrack and traverse the others

Comment: Yes, I also though that. I said your code only traverses one *complete/possible* path, that is, it visits every node once and then it finishes.

Comment: No, because on each recursive call it takes a copy of the visited array, so the nodes visited by one recursive call do not effect the nodes that another recursive call can visit. Does that make sense? (sorry if its not very clear, its hard to describe without pictures).

Comment: Yes, I understand, sorry. But you cannot use int for copy as it limits N to 32 (or 64) which makes the whole algorithm to O(1) (with a big constant, but that's still O(1)). If you need realy O() complexity measurement that variable has to be a two dimensional array, as in your code an then copy won't work with O(1).

Comment: Lol, thats fair enough. I suppose we can unclear the cell in the 2 dimensional array on the backtrack to avoid having to copy it and then the algorithm will be what is desired. Still I don't think it is O(n^2) I think its exponential, but was not sure hence posting the question. With this clarification do you still stick with n^2?

Comment: Yes, that's how a proper backtrack should work. No, I'm not stick to n^2 I already said sorry...